# Html Modal opens fine in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

My html code works fine in chrome but not in firefox. Issue happens when you click "see more" [modal] to see the description. I narrowed down to modal css property being the issue. When i change the position from fixed to relative, firefox it works but it messes with other style components. Can you please help here.

https://testhtmlcode.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-01-02.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Popoup in javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      outline: none;
      font-family: 'system-ui', 'sans-serif';
      font-weight: 300;
      transition: .3s linear 0s all;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;
      align-items: left;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin: 40px 0;
    }
    
    .container .card {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3747155/pexels-photo-3747155.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load) no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      margin: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border-radius: 15px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .container .card .content {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .container .card:hover .contentBx {
      transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    
    .container .card .content .contentBx h2 {
      color: #000000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 20px 0 10px;
      line-height: 1.1em;
    }
    
    .container .card .content .contentBx p {
      color: #ffffff;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 20px 0 10px;
      line-height: 1.1em;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .container .card .sci {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .container .card .sci li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 10px;
      transform: translateY(40px);
      transition: 0.5s;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .container .card:hover .sci li {
      transform: translateY(0px);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .container .card .sci li a {
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .blur-filter {
      filter: blur(2px);
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    [modal] {
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 120%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      color: white;
      background: #ffffff38;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 1s linear 0s all;
    }
    
    [modal="active"] {
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0%;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal {
      display: contents;
    }
    
    [modal]>.flexbox_column {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_header {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto 24px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_header>h4 {
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_header>._close {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 5px;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #e2e2e2;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #9a9a9a;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: #b6b6b6;
    }
    
    [modal]>.modal>.modal_content>img {
      max-width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      filter: opacity(0.8);
    }
    
    [data-modal] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <!--CARD START-->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="contentBx">
              <h2>PR1</h2>
              <p>
                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                <a data-modal>See more</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <!--MODAL START-->
            <div modal>
              <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                <div class="modal_header">
                  <h4>MEGA DISCOUNT</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                <div class="modal_content">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non
                    dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem! Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum
                    qui sint voluptatem. Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non
                    dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem! Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum
                    qui sint voluptatem. Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                  </p>
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--MODAL END-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--CARD END-->
        <!--CARD START-->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="contentBx">
              <h2>PR1</h2>
              <p>
                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                <a data-modal>See more</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--MODAL START-->
          <div modal>
            <div class="modal flexbox_column">
              <div class="modal_header">
                <h4>DISCOUNT 50%</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
              <div class="modal_content">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non
                  dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem! Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum
                  qui sint voluptatem. Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non
                  dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem! Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum
                  qui sint voluptatem. Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                </p>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--MODAL END-->
        </div>
        <!--CARD END-->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  let modalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-modal]');
  modalLinks.forEach(link =>
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
      openModal(link)
    })
  );

  function openModal(e) {
    const el = e.closest('.card');
    const modal = el.querySelector('[modal]');
    modal.setAttribute('modal', 'active');
  }

  function closeModal(e) {
    const modal = e.closest('[modal]');
    modal.setAttribute('modal', '');
  }
</script>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this code is working fine both in chrome and firefox, can you please verify this ?

Comment: tried but breaking in firefox when you click on see more

Comment: I am running your snippet in chrome and firefox but its working fine, it will be great if you can ss it with exact pain point.

Comment: attached the firefox screenshot

Comment: I checked in my browser, it showing property, above text and below image and proper alignment. please try in incognito mode of both chrome and firefox, or update your browser(although updating browser should not be the issue, but still try.)